# Error 91 when trying to copy all cells in a sheet. But only for some code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy all the data from the sheet "private" to a sheet called "topthree".

```
Dim r As Range
Sheets("private").Select
Set r = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
r.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("topthree").Range("A1")
```

The third row gives me the error: "Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

The weird thing is that I have the exact same code at the top of the macro.

```
Dim rng As Range
Sheets("eBS").Select
Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
r.Select
Selection.Copy Sheets("private").Range("A1")
```

And that code works just fine. What might be the problem here?
/Jens

Comment: what happens if you put `If r is nothing Then exit sub`before the `r.Select` and you step through the code with `F8`?

Comment: It could be that 'AutoFilter' on "private" sheet is off >> you should check the status of 'AutoFilter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `AutoFilter` is off.

Another thing, there's no need to use `'Select'` and `'Selection'` to copy a range from one sheet to another, see modified code below:

***Modified Code***

```
Dim r As Range

With Sheets("private")
    ' make sure Auto_filter is on
    If .AutoFilterMode = False Then
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter ' <-- in case your Auto-Filter range starts at cell "A1"
    End If

    Set r = .AutoFilter.Range
End With

' Copy >> Paste without selecting
r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("topthree").Range("A1")
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! By the way, why would you want to turn off Autofilter?

Comment: @Jens you wouldn't, the code just verifies that it's on

Comment: Ok! No I was just wondering why the option exists. Can it be a bad thing to leave it on? I'm a beginner at this VBA thing. :)

Comment: @Jens it's not bad at all, I'm keeping mine on. But sometimes, other users that use the same file as you, might turn it off, so you wanna make sure it's on